# Hiding Dynamically Created Buttons on click in Visual Basic Forms

Tags: vb.net, forms

Im currently trying to make dynamically created buttons disappear when clicked.

I have a Private Sub that handles when the button is clicked and increases the players score. However, i do not know how to make the specific object disappear as all the Objects are called the same name as they are created by the same subroutine set on a timer ( a new button made every 2 seconds).

I have tried adding every new button created to an array but am still struggling to make the program figure out which button has been clicked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One of the parameters on your button click event handler should be `sender As Object`, which is a reference to the button that was clicked. You just need to cast it to a button object, then set the `visible` property.

Comment: @Icemanind Thanks for the speedy response, I do have the sender as object parameter but  how exactly would I go about casting it to a button object? Very new at this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the parameters on your button click event handler should be `sender As Object`, which is a reference to the button that was clicked. You just need to cast it to a button object, the set the `Visible` property to false. Here is an example:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim b As Button = CType(sender, Button)
    b.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Works well ,Cheers mate really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Further to @Icemanind's answer, you can actually do it in one line:

```
CType(sender, Button).Visible = False
```

This works without validation because you *know* that `sender` is of type `Button`.

If you have multiple buttons to handle, you can also add additional events to the handler so you don't end up with a zillion individual handlers:

```
Protected Sub Button_Click(s As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles _
        Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click

    CType(s, Button).Visible = False
End Sub
```

Yet another option is to add the same handler to multiple buttons rather than adding buttons to the handler:

In Form instantiation (`Sub New()`):

```
AddHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf Button_Click
AddHandler Button2.Click, AddressOf Button_Click
AddHandler Button3.Click, AddressOf Button_Click
```

In Form class code:

```
Protected Sub Button_Click(s As Object, e As EventArgs)

    CType(s, Button).Visible = False
End Sub
```

This last method works well with dynamic controls because you can add the handlers on the fly:

```
Dim button As Button
For i As Integer = 0 To 9
    button = New Button With {.Name = $"Button{i}", .Text = $"Button{i}", .Left = 42, .Top = 50 + (i * 30)}
    Me.Controls.Add(button)
    AddHandler button.Click, AddressOf Button_Click
Next i
```

Comment: DirectCast is a bit faster.